# Best way to parse nested data in a string with custom delimiters

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I am trying a string this specific format (newline added for readibility, everything is on one line):

```
{
    {
        {
            {[item1];30;42;100}
        };
        70
    };
    {
        {
            {[item2];1;1;30.627};
            {[item3];1;1;22.8201};
            {[item4];1;1;46.5529}
        };
        33.529
    };
    {
        {
            {[item5];1;1;29.1262};
            {[item6];1;1;14.5631};
            {[item7];1;1;9.7087};
            {[item8];1;1;5.8252};
            {[item9];1;1;29.1262};
            {[item10];1;1;11.6506}
        };
        6.6988
    }
}
```

Items are split into groups, with every group having a number. Here we have three groups, with numbers 70, 33.529 and 6.6988

Groups can't have a nested group in them.

Within each group, item have three numbers, which I need to capture aswell.

I want to be able to capture the hierarchy between every item : in which group they are part of, and what's the chance of said group. How would I achieve this ?

I am thinking of two approaches :

- regexes, may be with the lookback tag ? Starting from an item, I can lookback to the group ?
- python, parsing the string line by line, and trying to determine what "state" I am in based of the amount of the characters met, like { } or ;

Any input is welcomed while I scratch my head. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing a grammar for your format, for example:

```
input = '{' groups '}'
groups = group | groups ';' group
group = '{' items ... etc
```

Then either feed this grammar to a parser generator or write a top-down parser by hand by replacing non-terminals with respective functions calling each other.